# "a team of graphics editors, designers and editors brought the project to life this month." is the statement correct?(It's taken from an article)

Tags: tense, past-tense, present-perfect, present-tense, past-simple

I think we can only use "this month" with the present perfect tense not with the past tense. Here 'this month' is used with past tense which is wrong I think because we specify the time while using simple past

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly correct.

The project has been finished; the act of bringing it to life took place over a period of time, and that period was earlier in the current month.

Comment: So we can use words like "this month" "this day" "this year" with simple past as well?

Comment: *I woke this day with a headache*

Comment: Well you'd say "today" rather than "this day", but yes.